# $.each not working with JavaScriptSerialized String Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, string, each, javascriptserializer

Trying to populate select with sql results using WebMethods.

I can get and pass the data, but I've noticed the format is [["",""],["",""]] instead of [{"",""},{"",""}].

When I use $.each, I get single characters as the select's options, each character from the output, including the JSON delimiters.

**VB**

```
Dim MArray()() As String = New String(sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows.Count)() {}
Dim i As Integer = 0

For Each rs As DataRow In sqlDataset.Tables(0).Rows
    MArray(i) = New String() {rs("suppliername").ToString(), rs("supplierid").ToString()}
    i = i + 1
Next

Dim js As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
Dim sJSON As String = js.Serialize(MArray)
Return sJSON
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SupplierAdmin.aspx/PopulateSupplierSelectDropDownList",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        $("#supplierSelect").empty();
        $.each(msg.d, function(name, value) {
                $('#supplierSelect').append($('<option>').text(name).attr('value', value));
            });
    }
});
});
```

Comment: In the alert, do you get `[object Object]`, a comma separated list of values, or the json string. It should be either `[object Object]` or a comma separated list of values. $.type(msg) should be `"array"` or `"object"`

Comment: Did you mean to type `$.each(this...)` or do you mean `$.each(msg.d`)?

Comment: sry about the alert.  i was only using that for testing.  deleted it.  what does 'this' in the place of 'msg.d' do?  I'm trying to populate the select with the data from the msg sent back from asp.net webmethod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the .each loop, try:

```js
for(var i=0; i < msg.d.length; i++) {
  $('#supplierSelect').append($('<option>').text(msg.d[i].name).attr('value', msg.d[i].value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing can also be done using $.each function

```
$.each(msg.d , function(i){
  $('#supplierSelect').append($('<option>').text(msg.d[i].name).attr('value', msg.d[i].value));
}
```